# Terrain generation array - C#

Tags: c#, xna, terrain

So, I'm trying to make a small program that generates chunks, as in 2 Texture2Ds'. I Made another class called Terrain_Plains.

Constructor (you can guess I already made the variables):

```
public Terrain_Plains(Texture2D chunkSprite, int y)
    {
        chunks = chunkSprite;
        this.y = y;

        //Load drawRectangle
        drawRectangle = new Rectangle(0, y, 50, 50);
    }
```

Then I made a draw method:

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(chunks, drawRectangle, Color.White);
    }
```

I made an array with the Terrain_Plains in the Game1 method:

```
Terrain_Plains[] terrain = new Terrain_Plains[2];
```

And then initialized it using a for loop.

Everything went as expected except one thing: It wasn't showing the 2nd `Terrain_Plains`.

How can I make them both side-by-side, without having to make another Rectangle? Reason I want to only use one Rectangle is because I want to add more than just 2 `Terrain_Plains`

EDIT FOR Preston Guillot:

for loop used to initialize array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            terrain[i] = new Terrain_Plains(sprite, WINDOW_HEIGHT - 50);
        }
```

for loop to draw the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            terrain[i].Draw(spriteBatch);
        }
```

Comment: Are you calling both Draw methods? Have you checked with a breakpoint that everything is working as you expect?

Comment: Yes, I did, I stated "everything went as expected," I checked the breakpoints as well, I even made another Rectangle that was the location of the 2nd "Terrain_Plains" THAT worked. But I'm trying to only use 1 drawRectangle.

Comment: If your program don't show a texture the only problems are that you are not calling the draw or you are drawing it in a wrong way, probably it's the second one. Can you add the for loop code that you use to initialize the terrain?

Comment: I don't think you get it. It worked **AS EXPECTED.** Except for **ONE** thing. Sorry to sound so rude. Everything worked fine, but it only displayed 1 texture, it was supposed to display 2, side-by-side. And if I were to add more to the array, it would display the amount I put it the array.

P.S. I edited in the for loop I used for intialization & drawing the array; in the post

Comment: You always pass `WINDOW_HEIGHT - 50`, that value doesn't change in your loop, so it seems that `drawRectangle` is the same for both terrains. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes that is possible. I tried right now changing the constructor for the Terrain_Plains, I added an argument, the argument was int x. Then I created a number integer, with that, in the for loop method I used to initialize my array, I added "number += 50;". and for the int x argument: "number - 50" That worked completely fine, heck I even added more to the array and it worked perfect. But, if I were to randomly draw it, would it still draw?(i.e: I create a random number that either calls 1 or 2, 1 calls this chunk, 2 calls another, No matter what I want them all to be side by side, no overlap)

Comment: If you have an array of terrain and you pick randomly one of them and you draw it, you will see only that chunk. Of course this depends on what you do in your terrain class.